# Add a page in admin without adding menu item

Tags: plugin-development, admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

In my plugin I have registered a `menu_page`; now I need another page.
How can I add another page to my plugin without adding another menu item?
Is it possible to call it by href?

Comment: Are you trying to add a subpage to your existing menu item?

Comment: I just need a page to call from the existing page linked to a menu item
I have a menu item 'my_plugin' that call function to render_my_plugin it requires my_plugin_main.html
inside it there are some choices 
these are href to my_plugin_page2 ...
I want to create my_plugin_page2.php without link to amenu item or subitem

Answer (score 0):

Try using `remove_menu_page()`.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_menu_page